# Instance of a functional component is said to be unrecognized in browser. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using a JSON format text file to import items from there to another js file using react. I am using the map method in JS to iterate through the item in the JSON file. However an error keeps popping up that  my functional component is unrecognized.

```
import React from "react"
import products from "./vschoolProducts"
import product from "./product"

function App() {
    const listofp = products.map(function(pro){
        return <product key={pro.id} product= {pro} />
    })
  return (
    <div>
      {listofp}  
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Any ideas of why it is unrecognized ?

Answer (score 0):

It's silly of me, but the error can be resolved simply by making the first letter of the react component in upper caps.

The `product` component in product.js needs to be changed to `Product`.
Subsequently every instance of `product` must be changed to `Product`.

Functional components must always start with Caps.